# Как корректно перезапустить celery worker?

Tags: python, django, celery

Как перезапустить celery worker так чтобы все текущие задачи которые начали выполнение завершились, но новые не стартовали, чтобы можно было внести определенные корректировки и перезапустить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по ответам с stackoverflow.com достаточно `kill -TERM pid`. Воркер перестает принимать новые задания и завершается после окончания тех что есть. Дальше супервизор перезапускает воркера.

Comment: мне нужно не перезапускать автоматически, а вручную сделать некоторые изменения. (пересобрать докер образ и перезапустить целиком)

Comment: тут ещё докер) ну так делай сборку, стоп, старт. Задачи завершаться нормально

Comment: всмысле просто Docker stop? работающие воркеры доработают?

Comment: The main process inside the container will receive `SIGTERM`, and after a grace period, `SIGKILL` если  grace period хватит, то доработают.

Comment: Понял, спасибо!

Comment: К примеру `docker stop -t 120 celery` чтоб дать 2 минуты на остановку.